# Dagger: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.SetMultimap.forEach(Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;)V

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I'm trying to use the new dagger android features however I appear to be getting this error during compilation:

```
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileStagingUsaDebugJavaWithJavac'.
...
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.SetMultimap.forEach(Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;)V
    at dagger.android.processor.AndroidMapKeyValidator.process(AndroidMapKeyValidator.java:114)
    at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:329)
    at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:182)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    ... 97 more
```

Has anyone else seen this error, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops looks like I had wrong version of gauva (was 19 should have been 20).